# Issues in converting base64 decoded byte array to String in java

Tags: java, base64

Issues in converting base64 decoded byte array to String in java :

```
 public static  String decode(String strcontent) throws Exception
 {
  BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
  byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(strcontent);
  return new String(imgBytes);
 }
```

With the above code; was trying to create a string out of the Base 64 decoded byte array (imgBytes ) & input strcontent is base 64 encoded string. For text files it working fine , but for PDF and image files the string conversion is having issues. Have tried different encoding as UTF-8 , UTF 16 etc. But no use. The returned string is different than the original one.

When tried to write the byte array to a file like :

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(@@path);
out.write(imgBytes);
out.close();
```

File is getting created properly without any issues.

I tried the below code:

```
byte[] imgBytes= ( new String(imgBytes1)).getBytes();  //Converting to    String and back to bytes
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(@@Filename); 
out.write(imgBytes); out.close();
```

This time the image file is corrupted.

Please suggest.

Comment: I want to send this to a webservice which expects a String input .This webservice will create the file.For txt files it was working ...but for images n PDFs it was not.    
I though its the problem with encoding  . 
If the byte array converted string is copied on to a .pdf/.jpg file; it should open without issues rt ? and it should match with the contents of the original .pdf /.jpg file saved as .txt.

Comment: Issue was resolved , as OSB was used to call the web services and there was compatibility issues with the jars used.When OSB specific jars were used for Base64 decoding the issue was gone.